# function or subroutine in C++ that takes an array and print it to a text file

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, cout

I am trying to write a function or subroutine in C++ that takes an array and print it to a text file. I know it is easy to do this in FORTRAN. I have not find a good way to do it in C++. Thanks

Comment: Pick up an introductory book. Read until you get to arrays and file output. Write the function. Ask when it's not working and you've done sufficient debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you have a `std::vector<float>` or a `float[]` style array, the process is similar.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

int main () {
  std::vector<float> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i*10.f);

  std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout,", ");
  std::copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), out_it );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
#include <iostream> // library that contain basic input/output functions
#include <fstream>  // library that contains file input/output functions
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char array[] = {'H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','!','\0'}; //array to write into file 

    ofstream fout("test.txt"); //opening an output stream for file test.txt
    /*checking whether file could be opened or not. If file does not exist or don't have write permissions, file
  stream could not be opened.*/
  if(fout.is_open())
    {
    //file opened successfully so we are here
    cout << "File Opened successfully!!!. Writing data from array to file" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
      fout << array[i]; //writing ith character of array in the file
        }
    cout << "Array data successfully saved into the file test.txt" << endl;
    }
    else //file could not be opened
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```